Effects of dielectric on force between charged bodies?
The electrostatic force between the plates of a charged isolated capacitor remains unchanged when dielectric fills whole space between plates.
But when we take 2 isolated point charges in a dielectric medium, the electrostatic force between them decreases as compared to the force in vacuum at the same separation.
I cannot understand why force remains unchanged in case of capacitor since the electric field is reduced due to dielectric so the force between the plates should also decrease?

the Capacitance of the plates also changes. If originally it was C in vaccum then, in a dielectric medium(K) its capacitance changes to KC. Refer to the HC Verma, Vol 2 pg 145(Calculation of capacitance of Parallel plate capacitor) and pg 152(Parallel plate capacitor with a dielectric)

The answer lies in the geometry of your capacitor. Imagine you have 2 point charges with a finite distance. You then expect an electric field outside the charges that looks somewhat like a dipole field. When looking at any point in space, the field generated by the closer particle will be larger then the field of the particle further away because the monopole fields will decay with $\frac{1}{r^2}$ and the overall field with $\frac{1}{r^3}$ at large distances.
If you instead look at 2 infinitely large parallel charged plates, the field of each plate will be constant in space, which can be envisioned easily considering, that the field lines are parallel at all points in space or be confirmed mathemathically using gauss law. For the field of your 2 oppositely charged large plates in your overall neutral system you get a constant field between the plates, where both field are parallel, and a zero field outside, where both fields cancel each other out.
Now lets try to look on the implications of the above observations for the behavior of a dielectricum: If you have a finite dimensioned dielectric body in a field, that body will be polarized by the field and generate a finite dipole or higher pole field outside the body, which will exert a force on the charges generating the polarizing original field, and decay at large distances with $\frac{1}{r^3}$ or faster.
If on the other hand you have an infinite dimensioned dielectric in between the 2 infinite dimensioned capacitor plates, you can imagine the polarized dielectric as a bunch of oppositely charged capacitor plates next to each other. As we discussed above in that geometry the opposite charges in the overall electrical neutral dielectric will likewise generate a field only in between them, but not outside the dielectric. That means the dielectric does not exert any force on the capacitor plates in that geometry.
